# AWS Lambda: Unable to import module 'package/file': No module named 'util'

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-3.6

I am struggling to get module importing to work in AWS lambda using Python 3.

My file structure looks like this:

```
package:
  stage1.py
  __init__.py
  util:
    helper1.py
    __init__.py
```

`helper1.py` is a simple util class:

```
def foo():
  print("yes")
```

Within `stage1.py` I have the following lines that cause Lambda to throw an error when it is starting:

```
from util.helper1 import foo
foo()
```

```
Unable to import module 'package/stage1': No module named 'util'
```

Both `__init__.py` files are empty.

Sadly, I see that this works if I invoke the script locally. Frustrating is an understatement!

Comment: `stage1.py` is being called by a handler in AWS Lambda

Comment: Invoking scripts a **within** a package like it was a standalone often doesn't work. [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) might be helpful (it has a lot of information on how packages work).

Comment: As you mentioned the directory structure, I created the same on the Lambda and it is working file. Can you please update the question with the screenshot of the directory structure in lambda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to some of the links sent above and my own (and necessary) research into how imports are handled in python, I figured out the issue regarding unavailable modules.

How I debugged my app in Lambda:
I attached this line of code to the top of the file

```
print("Name is ({})".format(__name__))
```

This gave me an output that could help me understand an make an educated decision on how to import the files in the `util` module. I saw an output for the `stage1.py` file was `packager/stage1`. This made the import code modifications easy to make.
I changed the imports in the `stage1.py` file to (using absolute path imports -- pep recommendation):

```
from packager.util.helper1 import foo
```

For whatever subjective reason, [this link](https://alex.dzyoba.com/blog/python-import/) helped me understand the process the most.

Answer (score 1):

I avoided this issue using a leading dot in the path like this

```
# package.py
from .util.helper1 import foo
```